# Asp.net MVC custom 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sick of the asp.net, just one question that

```
//EmpService.cs
Emplee emp = loadDataFromDB(emp_id);
if (emp == null) //Fail to get employee data
{
    this.custom404();
}
```

Based on the MVC framework, how do we handle the custom404 and finally return a custom 404 Not Found page to the user? Like how to define controllers, how to define views. A concrete example with codes would be better. Thanks!

Comment: Check this one http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config file place these code inside `<system.web></system.web>` and create `Error` controller and three actions `Error404` etc. and respective view pages. if `iis` returns `status 500` then the `Error404` page will be shown. You can create your own error pages.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```